Is there any way to render direct react component in the tooltip?
Is there any way to pass the React components directly in tolltip?
I want to make customizeable tooltip usin echarts in React Js.
We can do add the strings and HTMLElements
const options = {
    tooltip: {
            trigger: "item",
            enterable: true,
            formatter: (params) => {
                const { value, name } = params as { value: number; name: string };
                return `
                
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                    <div>${name}</div>
                    <div>${value}</div>
                </div>
                `;
            },
        },
}

But is there any way to pass the React component in it directly like
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const options = {
    tooltip: {
            trigger: "item",
            enterable: true,
            formatter: (params) => {
                const { value, name } = params as { value: number; name: string };
                return <Link to={'/'}> Navigate </Link>
            },
        },
}



If the library you're using expects a string, could something like this be used to convert the React components to a HTML string you can return: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString

No it does not work I already tried this, it gives error
Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'React2.useContext(...)' as it is null.
on
return renderToString(<Link to={"/"}> Navigate </Link>);
I even tried this one
https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString#alternatives
My main purpose is to use react link rather than anchor tags to avoid full page reload

this post may be what you are looking for.  have you wrapped your app in a BrowserRouter component?
